# Shipping timer condition for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods

I want to create a restriction on a shipping method that it can only be used 1 hour after the most recent use by a customer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by hooking into the class
`Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping` class's collectRates() function

Just store in a database somewhere or something when a customer uses it, then compare that (plus one hour) to the current timestamp.

If the current timestamp is bigger, then show the method.

Comment: Great can i get more details about your idea ?